# TF2 how to remove custom signature of SavedModel and re-exporting the model

Tags: keras, deep-learning, model, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-serving

I currently have a saved model, it is using a custom signature, but it needs to have serving_default signature def, so it should look like this: `signature_def['serving_default']`.

If I do `saved_model_cli show` it currently shows

```
signature_def['image_quality']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['input_image'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 224, 224, 3)
        name: input_1:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['quality_prediction'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 10)
        name: dense_1/Softmax:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Is there a way to remove the custom name and re-export the model in tensorflow 2 in order to have the serving_default signature?

Comment: Please checkout below link to specify signature during export for custom models:- https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#specifying_signatures_during_export

Comment: I read it and it shows how to go from default --> custom signature

Comment: What is the output for the following command ? :- 
saved_model_cli show --dir /path/to/model/folder --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default

Comment: I had found the original code and had resaved it to no longer have the custom output

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new model with the signature you want.

1. Load your model

```
M = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir='/path/to/saved/model')
```

2. Create a new model with the signature you want

```
class MyModel(tf.Module):
  def __init__(self, M):
    self.model = M

  @tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([(None, 224, 224, 3)], tf.float32)])
  def fn(self, image):
    output = self.model.signatures['image_quality'](image)
    return {
        'quality_prediction': outputs['quality_prediction'],
    }
  

pruned = MyModel(M)
tf.saved_model.save(
  pruned,
  '/path/where/you/want/your/new/model',
  signatures = {'serving_default': pruned.fn},
  options=tf.saved_model.SaveOptions(experimental_custom_gradients=False),
)
```

3. Test to make sure the signatures are as you expect:

```
E = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir='/path/where/you/want/your/new/model')

fn = E.signatures['serving_default']

print ("Inputs:")
for x in fn.inputs:
  print("  ", x)
print ("Outputs:")
for k,v in fn.structured_outputs.items():
    print("  ", k, v)
```